# API to parse PSD files

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am trying to parse Photoshop PSD files and I want to extract layer information, including text.

Is there any API in Objective-C that can help me to extract this information from PSD files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no framework  or 3rd party parser available for parsing the PSD file in Objective-C
But there is one available in C language, Which you could use with your objective-C code

Forum Source:

[Is there a PSD file parser for Objective-C? I want to replace a layer image and output the result as an NSImage.](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-PSD-file-parser-for-Objective-C-I-want-to-replace-a-layer-image-and-output-the-result-as-an-NSImage)

[load layers from a psd file at runtime?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12642)

[PSD file parser source code in C.](http://telegraphics.com.au/svn/psdparse/trunk/)